# Trouble with GroupBox and ListBox

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am having trouble with properly aligning the contents of my listbox. I have the following XAML. Basically, I am trying to show a number of ListBoxes, each under their own header. I am also attaching a screenshot. As you can see, only the ListBox with the longest TextBlock will have its X buttons right aligned properly. I have tried HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch", but that didn't work. I have also double checked that the ListBox, ListBoxItem, and GroupBox styles that I am including don't do anything weird. I've basically removed all styling and the problem persists. Any ideas? I am open to any ideas, including changing my XAML around.

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <GroupBox Header="{Binding Path=CategoryName}">
            <ListBox Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="15" SharedSizeGroup="Col1"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Col2"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Col3"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="11" SharedSizeGroup="Col4"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Path Grid.Column="0" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Stroke="{StaticResource Green06Brush}" StrokeThickness="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" Data="M 1 6 L 4 9 L 10 1" Margin="0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6" ClipToBounds="true" StrokeEndLineCap="Flat" StrokeStartLineCap="Flat"/>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Symbol}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,0,10,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>

                            <fpp:ImageButton Grid.Column="3" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" Source="Images/Clear_X.png" MouseOverSource="Images/Clear_X_On.png" DisabledSource="Images/Clear_X_Disabled.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="ClickRemoveTicker"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </GroupBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

**Original ScreenShot**

[image: Original Screenshot]

**Updated ScreenShot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each `Grid` is contained by an item container, and that container will only grow as large as its contents.

Try changing the `<GroupBox Header…>` element to this:

```
<GroupBox Header…
          Width="{Binding ActualWidth,
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}}">
```

In principle, this should set the width of all item `GroupBox`es equal to the width of the `ItemsControl` itself.

You may need to do the same thing with the `Grid`s, except you would bind to their `GroupBox` ancestor.

Now with all `Grid`s the same width, the buttons should line up on the right.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jay. I tried, but no dice. Here's a new screenshot: [link](http://i.imgur.com/g46Qy.png). When I set the Width on the Grid from the RelativeSource, horizontal scroll bars appear. I've changed the background of the grid to easily identify it. Still, its contents do not align nicely... Any ideas? **Edit:** I removed the SharedSizeGroups and now it seems to work fine. The scrollbars are still there, but I should be able to get rid of those. Thanks a bunch for your help!

Comment: @user1704151 Ha, I missed the screenshot link in your question, so I was just imagining it based on the XAML. The width of the items is a bit too large when set to the full width of the ancestor, hence the scrollbar. Not sure of the best solution there -- first thing that comes to mind is a converter that reduces the width value.

Comment: That is exactly what I ended up doing.